# apache poi workbook unique hashcode

Tags: apache-poi, hashcode

I'm trying to hash my workbook with apache poi using `workBook.hashCode()` function but the generated number is not unique for a workbook.
I use `System.identityHashCode(workBook)` too but it doesn't work.

how can I do this?

update:

```
String FILE_NAME = "/example.xlsx";
FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(new File(FILE_NAME));
Workbook book = WorkbookFactory.create(input);
int hash = System.identityHashCode(book);
```

or

```
int hash = book.hashCode();
```

or

```
int hash = new HashCodeBuilder().append(book).toHashCode();
```

Comment: what you mean its not unique for the workbook ? have you implemented the hashCode()? Also if you have, do  you shut down the JVM and reinvoking the method or its on a server and its producing the same hashes for different workbooks ?

Comment: no, I didn't shut down the jvm. I have a server and it produces different hashesh for the same workbook.

Comment: ok can you post your `hashCode()` implementation for the WorkBook

Comment: I didn't implemet the hashCode for the workbook. I use the apache poi default hashCode.

Comment: apache poi default ? you mean JDK's default ? cant find an implementation in their javadoc. The default `hashCode()` will get you a different hash for a  `new Object` with the same data

Comment: my question updated.
how can I hash the workbook object without overriding the apache poi workbook?

Comment: The hashcode returned by `System.identityHashcode()` will not be the same for different runs of your program or different instances. That's not what it is supposed to do. Did you really observe different hashcodes being returned for the same instance? What are you really trying to achieve? What problem do you want to solve?

Comment: I have different excel files and I want to insert them in the table but I want filter repeated files to prevent redundant excel files. it's not very import to do it exactly, I want to do it very simple without any compilicated implementation.

Comment: Each newly created Excel workbook contains the creation date and time within core document properties. So even if two workbooks are apart from that identically, this at least will distinguish them.

Comment: Tnx. Now how can I check if two workbooks are similar with hash?